# iText: Can I adjust the height of a table cell during rendering?

Tags: itext

I am generating a PdfPTable and adding it to a Chapter, and then adding the Chapter to my Document.  My table has several cells where RowSpan > 1, and sometimes those spans cross page boundaries, and when that happens I want the spanned cell to appear again.  In other words, if my table looks like this:

```
+------------------+------------------+
| Cell 1 RowSpan=1 | Cell 2 RowSpan=3 |
+------------------+------------------+
| Cell 3 RowSpan=1 |                  |
+------------------+------------------+
| Cell 4 RowSpan=1 |                  |
+------------------+------------------+
```

but when printed, there's a page break between rows 2 and 3, I want the table to look like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
+--------+        |
| Cell 3 |        |
+--------+--------+
Page Break
+--------+--------+
| Cell 4 | Cell 2 |
+--------+--------+
```

This is working thanks to a trick I learned here, I have a class which implements IPdfPCellEvent which I instantiate and attach to cells that have RowSpan > 1:

```
public class CellEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    Phrase m_phrase;
    bool m_first = true;

    public CellEvent(Phrase phrase)
    {
        m_phrase = phrase;
    }

    void IPdfPCellEvent.CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle r, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        if (m_first)
            m_first = false;
        else
        {
            ColumnText ct = cell.Column;
            ct.Canvases = canvases;
            m_phrase.Leading = m_phrase.Font.Size;
            ct.AddElement(m_phrase);
            ct.Go();
        }
    }
}
```

If the CellLayout() gets called more than once, the subsequent calls are happening because the RowSpan has spilled onto a new page (the exact situation I described above) and so I manually re-draw the cell text.  This works great.

Except.

If my cell 2 is taller than my cell 1:

```
+------------------+-------------------------+
| Cell 1 RowSpan=1 | Cell 2 Line 1 RowSpan=2 |
|                  | Cell 2 Line 2           |
+------------------+-------------------------+
| Cell 3 RowSpan=1 |                         |
+------------------+-------------------------+
```

And the table breaks between those two rows, what I see is this:

```
+--------+---------------+
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 Line 1 |
|        | Cell 2 Line 2 |
+--------+---------------+
Page Break
+--------+---------------+
| Cell 3 | Cell 2 Line 1 |
+--------+---------------+
```

Because, of course, the table has no idea that I want to draw two lines worth of text in row #2.

I can set row #2 to always be tall enough for two lines, but then if the table happens to fall in such a way that there isn't a page break between rows #1 and #2, it generates unnecessary white space in row #2:

```
+--------+---------------+
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 Line 1 |
|        | Cell 2 Line 2 |
+--------|               |
| Cell 3 |               |
|        |               | <- un-necessary space
+--------+---------------+
```

I tried adding a class that implements IPdfPTableEvent and attaching it to my document, but it appears that TableLayout() is called after all the layout has been performed, so I don't have a chance to sneak in and adjust row heights.

I think I can use PdfPTable.KeepRowsTogether() to prevent page breaks in the middle of row spans, but that's not the preferred format.

Is there a way to "get involved" with the layout of the table, as it's being rendered into the PDF document, so that I can adjust the height of the row?

p.s. I just created a subclass of PdfPTable where I override GetRowHeight(idx) and return the row height I want.  It has no effect on the resulting PDF.

Comment: It's been years since I last touched itext but this sounds familiar. Have you tried setting the `PdfPCell.Header` to `true` on cell 2

Comment: I hadn't noticed that before ... PdfPCell has an AddHeader() function and a read-only Headers property.  I'll have to research to see how they work ...

Comment: I have no idea what the PdfPHeaderCell class does, when I create one and add it to my cell there's no difference in the resulting PDF, and I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: @BettyCrokker, unrelated to your question but you've asked a bunch of questions here about iText and you've even stumped me on occasion! I'm really curious as to what you're cooking over there! (I get that you might not be able to tell anyone, but I'm still curious!)

Comment: Anyway, if I'm understanding what you're trying to do I think your only option is to run the table creation twice, once to figure out what to do before it happens and once to actually do it. In the pre-run (to a `MemoryStream` somewhere with the same page dimensions) you'll want to "record" things using a `IPdfPTableEvent` or a `IPdfPCellEvent` and then "play them back" using `IPdfPTableEventSplit` or `IPdfPCellEvent`.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, we've got some project management software that stores our information reasonably well, but is sorely lacking in terms of output.  I'm writing a C# program that accesses the database and uses iTextSharp to generate really nice-looking PDF reports.  Thanks for your help with my many questions!

Comment: I'm thinking that your solution would actually end up very iterative - imagine a table that is 10 pages long.  I run the table creation into memory, see that the first row on page #2 needs to be made taller.  I do so, but now need to re-run the table creation since that might have pushed all the rows down.  I now see that the first row on page #3 needs to be made taller ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with, is non-iterative (see @ChrisHaas' idea in the comments) but took a bit more code.  The code is kind of a mess (reflecting all the iterations I took to figure out the solution) so I'm not going to upload it all, but the basic gist is:

```
public class TableRowInfo
{
    public int height;
}
public class TableEvent : IPdfPTableEventAfterSplit
{
    Dictionary<PdfPRow, TableRowInfo> m_rows = null;
    public bool LoadSpans(PdfPTable table)
    {
        // Fill in m_rows, mapping PdfPRow to information about the height
        // of cells in that row, keeping row-spanning in mind
    }
    void IPdfPTableEventAfterSplit.AfterSplitTable(PdfPTable table, PdfPRow rowToStartNextPage, int startIdx)
    {
        TableRowInfo rowInfo = m_rows[rowToStartNextPage];
        if (rowInfo.height > rowToStartNextPage.MaxHeights)
        {
            PdfPCell[] cells = rowToStartNextPage.GetCells();
            foreach (PdfPCell cell in cells)
            {
                if (cell != null)
                    cell.MinimumHeight = rowInfo.height;
            }
            rowToStartNextPage.MaxHeights = rowInfo.height;
        }
    }
}
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(...);
// Fill in the rows of the table here
table.TableEvent = new TableEvent();
table.TableEvent.LoadSpans(table);
```

Comment: can you post some code? I have the same problem and don't know how to fix it based on your indications.

Comment: I've updated my response so it's actual code rather than just talking about code, hopefully that will get you going in the right direction.